# Си, линейные списки и файлы

Tags: c, структуры-данных, списки

Задача: Дана последовательность действительных чисел a1,a2,..., an( n >= 2 и заранее неизвестно). Если последовательность упорядочена по неубыванию, то оставить её без изменения, иначе получить последовательность an, a(n-1), ...., a1.

В общем нужно читать из файла и проверять.
Вопрос только в том, как проверить то, что в файле и понять упорядочена по неубыванию последовательность или нет?

Вот что я сделал:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
struct node
{
int data;
node* next;
};
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
FILE *hello;
node *p, *q;
fopen_s(&hello, "hello.txt", "r"); 
if (hello == NULL)
{
        printf_s("Ошибка открытия файла");
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
    int ch;
    p = new node;
    fscanf_s(hello, "%d", &ch);
    p->data = ch;
    int k = 1, j = 0;
    q = p;

    while (fscanf_s(hello, "%d", &ch) != EOF)
    {
        q -> next = new node;
        q = q->next;
        q->data = ch;
    }
    q->next = NULL;
    fclose(hello);
}
```

Подпрограмма для разворота списка тоже есть

```
void reverse(node*& head) 
{
if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
    return;

node* prev = nullptr;
node* next = nullptr;

while (head)
{
    next = head->next;      
    head->next = prev;
    prev = head;
    head = next;        
}
head = prev;
}
```

Comment: Раз уж вы все равно считываете всю последовательность в память - просто проходите по ней и убеждайтесь, что каждое следующее число не меньше предыдущего. Если встретите строго меньшее - значит, упорядоченности по неубыванию нет...

Comment: @harry как это лучше сделать?

Comment: У вас же список? ну вот и пишите цикл с проверкой вроде `if (q->next && q->data <= q->next->data)`

Comment: Всегда запускайте сортировку, это будет в среднем эффективнее, если предполагаются, что вероятность появления упорядоченной последовательности на входе не больше вероятности для неупорядоченной.